# Why this code of java works (instance inside if condition)

Tags: java

I would like to know why this code works, in which I am instantiating an object within an if block, and this object has scope outside the if block throughout the code. The particularity of this case is that it only works if the condition is false and if it has the respective throw Exception in case it is true. If the condition is left without negation or without the throw, this object is no longer accessible anywhere in the code. Here is an example of code that works exactly as I mentioned, but I would like to understand the reason for this since I have not found a formal explanation on the internet.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    public static void procesarDatos(Map<String, Object> datos) {
        if (!(datos.get("tipo") instanceof String tipo && tipo.equals("A"))) {

            throw new RuntimeException("Error");
        }
        System.out.println(tipo);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Object> datosA = new HashMap<>();
        datosA.put("tipo", "A");
        procesarDatos(datosA);

    }
}
```

I tried to understand what happen with this code, why it works because i dont found any information about it

Comment: Variables like `int i;` or `String s` have limited scope, but objects created on the heap (with `new`) persist until the garbage collector removes them.  Since the method throws an exception, that exception is potentially accessible to all methods that called the method that throws it.  So it's obviously (I guess, if you know Java well) not going to be collected and is going to persist outside of that method.

Comment: Clever (or sneaky) alternative, if you want one: if you test `"A".equals(tipo)` you don't need to first check `tipo instanceof String` because [String.equals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) does it automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the document: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/language/pattern-matching-instanceof-operator.html#GUID-843060B5-240C-4F47-A7B0-95C42E5B08A7

> The scope of a pattern variable are the places where the program can
> reach only if the instanceof operator is true
>
> The scope of a pattern variable can extend beyond the statement that
> introduced it

In your case, `tipo` is accessible because it is instance of String even if it is out of the block that introduced it

Answer (score 3):

From [JEP 394: Pattern Matching for `instanceof`](https://openjdk.org/jeps/394):

> The flow scoping analysis for pattern variables is sensitive to the notion of whether a statement can [complete normally](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.22). For example, consider the following method:
>
> ```java
> public void onlyForStrings(Object o) throws MyException {
>     if (!(o instanceof String s))
>         throw new MyException();
>     // s is in scope
>     System.out.println(s);
>     ...
> }
> ```
>
> This method tests whether its parameter `o` is a `String`, and throws an exception if not. It is only possible to reach the `println` statement if the conditional statement has completed normally. Because the contained statement of the conditional statement can never complete normally, this can only occur if the conditional expression has evaluated to the value `false`, which, in turn, means that the pattern matching has succeeded. Accordingly, the scope of the pattern variable `s` safely includes the statements following the conditional statement in the method block.

Your code is pretty much exactly the case described above.